# Connect Wifi 6 devices on old routers that does not have Wifi 6

Tags: wireless-networking

I'm thinking to buy a new laptop that has only WiFi 6 (802.11ax).
I want to know , can this laptop connect to older routers that does not have Wifi 6 ?

Answer (score 1):

If the Wireless card is Dual Band, it will connect albeit at a lower (N) speed.

My laptop does . The Intel NIC is dual band.

Wireless is generally backward compatible so you should be fine.

You may wish to contact the manufacturer to be sure.

Comment: does not say anything about dual band on specifications.

Comment: Wireless is generally backwards compatible so you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

All Wireless cards in laptops are backwards compatible with most older standards. As long as your access point isn't very, very old - you should be fine.

The most used cards from Intel and Broadcom are compatible with 802.11 a/b/g/n/ac standards (all previous standards except the original 802.11 from 1997).

- 802.11 a and ac use the 5 GHz band
- 802.11 b, g and n use the 2.4 GHz band
- 802.11 ax uses both the 2.4 and 5 GHz bands* (and 6 GHz band for WIFI 6E)

Unless the access point / wireless router is older than 7-8 years its's probably WIFI 5, and will connect on 5Ghz (ac) when you're close to the unit and fall back to 2.4GHz (n) if there are obstructions in the way.

- Note: some early WIFI 6 equipment did not use ax in the 2.4 GHz band, they fell back to n.